# "warning: invalid format string conversion" [printf-like-function] only in a CUDA source file

Tags: gcc, cuda, printf

Using the `'` format specifier in a `printf-like-function` leads to the warning.

```
class LogController
{
    auto __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))
         insertLogEntry( const char * formatString, ... ) -> void;
}

...
LogController lc;
lc.insertLogEntry( "Some data %'d", int_value );   // warning in .cu file
                                                   // in .cpp file OK
```

I have the feeling this is an `nvcc` issue and the only way to avoid the warning is to ***move*** the one line `foo.insertLogEntry()` into a `.cpp` file.

Even it is in a `.cu` file it is a `host` and NOT a `device` function. Any idea how to get rid of the warning?

**Update:**

> The `'` is according to this [site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) an [extension supported on all
>   POSIX.1-2008-conforming systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#CX).
>   The question is if `cudafe` does have to support this or not, even the underlying compiler is
>   `gcc 4.9.3`?

**Update:**

As **talonmies** suggested to use `--dryrun`, this causes the warning:

> `cudafe --allow_managed --m64 --gnu_version=40903 --c++11 -tused
>   --no_remove_unneeded_entities --debug_mode  --gen_c_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-4_CudaDevice.cudafe1.c"
>   --stub_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-4_CudaDevice.cudafe1.stub.c"
>   --gen_device_file_name "/tmp/tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-4_CudaDevice.cudafe1.gpu" --nv_arch
>   "compute_30" --gen_module_id_file --module_id_file_name
>   "/tmp/tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-3_CudaDevice.module_id"
>   --include_file_name "tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-2_CudaDevice.fatbin.c" "/tmp/tmpxft_000026f9_00000000-7_CudaDevice.cpp1.ii"`

I have to admit that I have no clue what I can do next...

**Update**:

```
OS: SLES 11 SP3
NSight 7.5
gcc 4.9.3 with -Wall -Werror -Wextra
```

**Update:**

Using `const char *` for the format string is not an option because I want to keep the format check performed by the compiler.

Comment: You do understand the nvcc isn't *compiling* this code (nvcc isn't a compiler), gcc is, after preprocessing by the cuda front end. So all this can be is default compiler options set by nvcc. If you use --dryrun you can see what options are being set by nvcc for the run

Comment: @talonmies: I never mentioned nvcc is compiling the code. The warning appears only in a cu file, therefore it is a nvcc problem. I think the best will be to extract this line into a cpp file and then it works and I get notified when there is a problem in the format/parameter list.

Comment: Right becuase nvcc is setting a gcc compiler option you don't want. Just work out which one it is, disable it for this file and your problem is solved.

Comment: I don't think there's much that can be done.  The issue as you've pointed out is arising from `cudafe` which is part of the CUDA toolchain, and not part of any gnu tools.  I've already filed a bug internally with NVIDIA, and I believe it's been acknowledged as an issue.  It may be fixed sometime in the future. Possible workarounds that I can think of would be the one I described in my answer, or else move the offending code to a `.cpp` file instead of a `.cu` file in your project.  I acknowledge that you've already stated that the first workaround is unacceptable. I point it out for posterity.

Comment: You can also file your own bug with NVIDIA if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark from NVIDIA confirmed this bug and it will be fixed in CUDA 8.

*For the moment I extracted the log messages into a .cpp file to avoid the warnings each time I compile the project.*

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to get rid of the warning?

Try this:

```
LogController lc;
const char * my_fmt = "Some data %'d";
lc.insertLogEntry( my_fmt, int_value );
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that using `const char` is not an option because then the whole format check is disabled and I want to keep it.